# word for person who thinks about himself/herself and cannot hear what other people say because of his/her curiosity

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word for a person who thinks about himself and cannot hear what other people say because he is too curious about something.

For example, Macbeth's reaction after he got the prediction from witches.

Comment: Could you provide example sentences where the word would be used?

Answer (score 3):

"[Zoned out](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/zone+out)" is a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You can say he was ***[deaf](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deaf)***  to their warnings/predictions:

> - unwilling  or refusing to listen; heedless: *was deaf to our objections.*

(AHD)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with **space out**.

> :  to become inattentive, distracted, or mentally remote: *spaced out
>   halfway through the lecture*

[**M-W**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/space%20out)

Answer (score 1):

That person seems to be ***self-absorbed***.

ODO:

> **[self-absorbed](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/self-absorbed)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> Preoccupied with one's own feelings , interests, or situation.
>   ‘they
>   are too self-absorbed to listen carefully to others’

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, I’d suggest that Macbeth’s reaction to the Witches’ predictions arose from his “[**overconfidence**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overconfidence_effect).”

(“Overconfidence has been called the most 'pervasive and potentially catastrophic' of all the cognitive biases to which human beings fall victim.[25] It has been blamed for lawsuits, strikes, wars, and stock market bubbles and crashes.” From Wikipedia’s discussion of the “Overconfidence Effect”)

His overconfidence prevented him from hearing/interpreting the predictions in any way that could adversely affect his charmed destiny, and his misinterpretation of them (as things that could not possibly occur) in turn only added to his feeling of invincibility, which led to arrogance and his eventual downfall.

Answer (score 0):

The person has a *one-track mind*. Or the person is *oblivious* to what others are saying.

Answer (score -1):

Macbeth is trying to convince himself that the witches didn't tell the truth. He is **incredulous**.

*Definition: disinclined or indisposed to believe; skeptical; showing unbelief; unwilling to admit or accept what is offered as true*.

Answer (score -2):

Self Confidence. This could be anywhere where a person could think about themself. It could possibly range from amazing to terrible, etc.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! This could be made to work in some sentences, but is vague and doesn't directly all of the OP's ideas about what the word should be. Try to think of a word that fully matches what the question is about, not just one that could work sometimes.